# Prometheus not connected to alert manager in GKE

Tags: monitoring, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus

I installed kube-prometheus-stack 15.3.1 into a GKE cluster using helm (in "monitoring" namespace). I used the `values.yaml` to open up ingresses on some of the components and to add SMTP info and reciever details into the alert manager. For the most part everything seems fine, except Prometheus is firing a number of alerts, and I'm not getting any alert emails.

One firing alert is:

```
PrometheusNotConnectedToAlertmanagers
```

> Prometheus
> monitoring/prometheus-kube-prometheus-stak-prometheus-0 is not
> connected to any Alertmanagers

Another one is:

```
PrometheusOperatorSyncFailed
```

> Controller alertmanager in monitoring namespace fails to reconcile 1 objects.

I've also tried opening an ingress to the alertmanager and pointed `alerts.mydomiain.com` to it, but when I try to any GET requests (such as `alerts.mydomain.com/v2/status`) I always get a 502 server error.

What do I need to do to get my alertmanager working?

here is the output of `kubectl get pods,svc,daemonset,deployment,statefulset -n monitoring`:

```
NAME                                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-grafana-58f7fcb497-hm72h              2/2     Running   0          30h
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics-6d588499f5-d957b   1/1     Running   0          2d3h
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-operator-54f89674c9-k8ml7             1/1     Running   0          2d3h
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-22vpd        1/1     Running   0          3h57m
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-2qsl9        1/1     Running   0          3h57m
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-4d27n        1/1     Running   0          7h36m
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-7rlnk        1/1     Running   0          4h47m
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-7xlf4        1/1     Running   0          4h51m
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-9mfnt        1/1     Running   0          3h57m
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-9zblf        1/1     Running   0          2d3h
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-bdcjj        1/1     Running   0          2d3h
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-bs54w        1/1     Running   0          4h47m
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-fp95h        1/1     Running   0          2d3h
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-h4zhw        1/1     Running   0          2d3h
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-pz8js        1/1     Running   0          3h58m
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-rrrhk        1/1     Running   0          27h
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-rszlt        1/1     Running   0          2d3h
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-s62wq        1/1     Running   0          4h47m
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-w9dmb        1/1     Running   0          5h32m
pod/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter-xqmxk        1/1     Running   0          4h51m
pod/prometheus-kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-0               2/2     Running   1          30h

NAME                                                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/kube-prometheus-stack-alertmanager               NodePort    10.125.4.161    <none>        9093:30903/TCP   2d3h
service/kube-prometheus-stack-grafana                    NodePort    10.125.7.177    <none>        80:32444/TCP     2d3h
service/kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics         ClusterIP   10.125.2.56     <none>        8080/TCP         2d3h
service/kube-prometheus-stack-operator                   ClusterIP   10.125.4.171    <none>        443/TCP          2d3h
service/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus                 NodePort    10.125.13.11    <none>        9090:30090/TCP   2d3h
service/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter   ClusterIP   10.125.10.231   <none>        9100/TCP         2d3h
service/prometheus-operated                              ClusterIP   None            <none>        9090/TCP         2d3h

NAME                                                            DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus-node-exporter   17        17        17      17           17          <none>          2d3h

NAME                                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/kube-prometheus-stack-grafana              1/1     1            1           2d3h
deployment.apps/kube-prometheus-stack-kube-state-metrics   1/1     1            1           2d3h
deployment.apps/kube-prometheus-stack-operator             1/1     1            1           2d3h

NAME                                                           READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/prometheus-kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus   1/1     42h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that the alertmanager pod was missing even though the service was there. I found I could get the pod back by uninstalling the prometheus stack then reinstalling it with default values, then upgrading it with my own values.

Now the PrometheusNotConnectedToAlertmanagers alert had stopped firing, but still I was not getting emails. Now I could access the alert manager through the ingress and see that the config for it that I had put in the Helm values file did not go through to the alert manager - it still had default config.

I found I was having the [issue described here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/393) and checking the logs in the kube-prometheus-stack operator pod confirmed it. I needed to have a "null" receiver in my alert manager receivers (which I had removed)

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anybody here from Google, I saw the error in the pods (I don't remember if it was Prometheus or Prometheus-operator) that the port was missing in the SMTP host and then realized I forgot to specify the port in the SMTP configuration when setting up the Alert Manager. I am using OpenShift 4.7 (if that matters)